# What does the letter R represent in chemical structures?

Tags: nomenclature

The letter $\ce{R}$ appears frequently in chemical structure illustrations. For instance, when I Google keratin, I find Wikipedia's [Spanish article](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queratina) about it.

In the image illustrating part of the chemical structure, I see elements like $\ce{H, C, O, N, and S}$ - which I recognize - but I also see $\ce{R}$, which I do not. What does $\ce{R}$ stand for in this context?

Comment: Related: [What is the correct way to illustrate a bond to something irrelevant in a structural formula?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/58899/7951)

Comment: I'm wondering if we could make this more general so that it would be googleable.  I'm sure it's a common question.

Answer (score 8):

Depending on the context, the letter R can stand for several things. From our friends teaching organic chemistry at [UCLA](http://www.chem.ucla.edu/~harding/IGOC/R/r_group.html):

> R group: An abbreviation for any group in which a carbon or hydrogen atom is attached to the rest of the molecule. Sometimes used more loosely, to include other elements such as halogens, oxygen, or nitrogen. R is an abbreviation for radical, when the term radical applied to a portion of a complete molecule (not necessarily a free radical), such as a methyl group. Should not be confused with R (the gas constant), R (the one-letter abbreviation for the amino acid arginine) or R (a designation of absolute configuration).

In the image from the Wikipedia article you have referenced, the letter R is as defined in the first section of the above quote - that is, it stands for "any group in which a carbon or hydrogen atom is attached to the rest of the molecule."

Comment: I thought that $\ce{R}$ originates from German "*der Rest*" (English "*residue*"), and the word "*radical*" was just an adaptation. I wonder if native German speakers could comment on this.

Comment: @andselisk That's how German teachers and textbooks use it, yes. Your translation is wrong however,  _residue_ is "Rückstand" in German (e.g. from a distillation). The two words can be synonymous, but not here. "der Rest" better translates as _rest of the molecule, R_.